# data.table shift() in v1.15.2 not working when rows are subset in i by column - `DT[i == TRUE, (cols) := shift(), by = col]`

Tags: r, data.table

Using data.table **v1.14.2** (R 4.2.1 - edited: also with v1.14.8 with R 4.2.3), I was able to use shift() to assign new columns in `j` by group after rows in `i` were subset. The same code is not working now using data.table **v1.15.2** (R 4.3.3).

Here is some sample data

```
set.seed(1)
data <- data.table(iris)[Species %in% c(
    'versicolor', 'virginica'
), .(Species, value = Petal.Width)][, .SD[1:8], by = Species]
data[, to.keep := runif(.N) > .3]
data # N:16, N[TRUE]:11

#        Species value to.keep
#  1: versicolor   1.4   FALSE
#  2: versicolor   1.5    TRUE
#  3: versicolor   1.5    TRUE
#  4: versicolor   1.3    TRUE
#  5: versicolor   1.5   FALSE
#  6: versicolor   1.3    TRUE
#  7: versicolor   1.6    TRUE
#  8: versicolor   1.0    TRUE
#  9:  virginica   2.5    TRUE
# 10:  virginica   1.9   FALSE
# 11:  virginica   2.1   FALSE
# 12:  virginica   1.8   FALSE
# 13:  virginica   2.2    TRUE
# 14:  virginica   2.1    TRUE
# 15:  virginica   1.7    TRUE
# 16:  virginica   1.8    TRUE
```

Using **data.table v1.14.2** (R 4.2.1), I am able to create lag columns by group considering only certain values in `i`:

```
mycols <- paste0('lag.', 1:3)
data[to.keep == TRUE, (mycols) := shift(value, n = 1:3, type = 'lag'), by = Species]
data
#        Species value to.keep lag.1 lag.2 lag.3
#  1: versicolor   1.4   FALSE    NA    NA    NA
#  2: versicolor   1.5    TRUE    NA    NA    NA
#  3: versicolor   1.5    TRUE   1.5    NA    NA
#  4: versicolor   1.3    TRUE   1.5   1.5    NA
#  5: versicolor   1.5   FALSE    NA    NA    NA
#  6: versicolor   1.3    TRUE   1.3   1.5   1.5
#  7: versicolor   1.6    TRUE   1.3   1.3   1.5
#  8: versicolor   1.0    TRUE   1.6   1.3   1.3
#  9:  virginica   2.5    TRUE    NA    NA    NA
# 10:  virginica   1.9   FALSE    NA    NA    NA
# 11:  virginica   2.1   FALSE    NA    NA    NA
# 12:  virginica   1.8   FALSE    NA    NA    NA
# 13:  virginica   2.2    TRUE   2.5    NA    NA
# 14:  virginica   2.1    TRUE   2.2   2.5    NA
# 15:  virginica   1.7    TRUE   2.1   2.2   2.5
# 16:  virginica   1.8    TRUE   1.7   2.1   2.2
```

However, trying the same code in **data.table v1.15.2** (R 4.3.3) results in the following error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(data, to.keep == TRUE, `:=`((mycols), shift(value,  : 
  Supplied 16 items to be assigned to 11 items of column 'lag.1'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Of course there are alternatives to achieve my goal. For instance, I can make a redundant row subsetting in `j`:

```
data[to.keep == TRUE, (mycols) := shift(value[to.keep == TRUE], n = 1:3, type = 'lag'), by = Species]
```

However, I understand that the original code should work as well. Do I miss anything?

I have checked for changes in the docs (`man/shift.Rd`) or function definition (`R/shift.R`) but have not found any relevant change (for instance, I have tried using `shift(..., fill='NA')` with same results). I have not found any related question in stackoverflow neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Edit: fix is now on CRAN (1.15.4+)

Unfortunately, you were affected by a regression in versions 1.15.0 and 1.15.2: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5962.

That issue is now fixed on CRAN as of v1.15.4.

You didn't find any change in shift.R since the relevant change is in `gshift()`, the group-optimized lag computation that was added for 1.15.0. This is only used in `[` queries.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the efforts.

Comment: BTW, as a workaround until it's published, you can qualify `data.table::shift` and this will stop GForce from working.

Comment: thanks for the tip.I tried to do so by calling `shift <- \`::\`('data.table', 'shift')` once in the main script. However, when shift is used inside a data.table, R obviously looks for shift definition in data.table's namespace first. Thus, I would need to replace all `shift()` calls with `data.table::shift()`. This is doable, but I rather wait a couple of weeks. Thanks

Comment: That's right -- your call is edited by looking for any call to `shift()` and replacing it with `GShift`. You could also turn off optimization generally (`options(datatable.optimize=0)`) but that will slow down the whole script.